# Get my own domain on WordPress.com

Tags: wordpress.com

How can I point a custom domain to my WordPress.com blog?

Comment: This is a wordpress.com question NOT a regular wordpress question, for your information, whoever changed that. Thanks, no offense taken in the least.

Comment: @Arien only Wordpress.com questions are allowed here. Hence questions tagged with `wordpress` are wordpress.com questions. Please roll back the edit. :)

Comment: @Arien see http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-should-we-do-with-wordpress-questions-and-how-tag-them/203#203

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom domains are [a paid upgrade.](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/)

> The Domain Mapping Upgrade allows you to use a custom domain name such as example.com instead of the standard WordPress.com domain name – example.wordpress.com – for your blog. This is a paid upgrade.

Wordpress.com has [a tutorial on doing this](http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/map-existing-domain/) once you've bought the upgrade.

Comment: You can add this from your admin control panel.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to set up your domain with your own hosting and install the [Wordpress application](http://wordpress.org/download/) there.

> With our famous 5-minute installation,
>   setting up WordPress for the first
>   time is simple. We’ve created a handy
>   guide to see you through the
>   installation process. If you're
>   upgrading your existing installation,
>   we've got a guide for that, too. And
>   should you run into any trouble along
>   the way, our support forums are a
>   great resource, where seasoned
>   WordPress experts volunteer their time
>   to help you get the most out of your
>   blog.

Comment: Having done that, you can reclaim many of the advantages of being hosted by `wordpress.com` with their [JetPack plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/), possibly giving you the best of both worlds. But remember that if you install your own wordpress, you are responsible for keeping patched and up to date, not to mention avoiding bugs or vulnerabilities introduced by plugins you do choose to add.